# Select2 dropdown showing sometimes duplicate

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I have added approx 10 fields in my view page of select2 dropdown using knockout Js but only few of them being duplicate which is multi select.

**Html**

```
<div class="multiselect" data-bind="css: { 'pink-selectbox' : Passengers() == null || Passengers() == '' }">
                            <select class="multipleAccom" data-bind="attr: { name:'['+$index()+'].Passengers' ,id: $index()+'_Passengers' },options: $root.PassengerList,selectedOptions:Passengers, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value',event: {change: $root.CheckPassengerAssignment.bind($data,$index())},valueAllowUnset : true" multiple="multiple"></select></div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('.multipleAccom').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        numberDisplayed: 0,
    });
```

[image]

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: edit your question and add code there.

Comment: @yılmaz please find edited question.

Comment: Can you create fiddle or snippet to reproduce the issue? ([Here's a custom binding implementation you can use](http://jsfiddle.net/ossipoff/nwzmv61q/)) Also, why do you have bootstrap's `multiselect()`? Aren't you supposed to do something like `$('.multipleAccom').select2()`?

Answer (score 1):

It was knockout issue, my DOM is not updating the values that time and select2 pulgin called, after populating data in DOM select2 reinitialized so it's duplicating dropdown.